# Automate turning on and off Twixtor effect in After Effects

Tags: after-effects

While using Twixtor in After Effects, you can automate the speed of the clip by manipulating the "Speed %" under "Output Control". Now, since there's no good way to do time-remapping natively in After Effects (rather, you'll have to automate specific time codes yourself, as stated in [this thread](http://forums.creativecow.net/thread/2/949299), which is a total drag), I'd like to use Twixtor's controls even when I don't need to use the frame interpolation it offers.

For example, let's say I'm running a 60 frames per second clip first at 100% speed, then at 40% speed, and then at 20% speed. When running the clip at 100% and 40%, I do already have enough information contained in the clip and won't need Twixtor's interpolation feature (it might even destroy my footage by affecting it when it's really not needed). It's only at 20% that I'll need it.

Is there some way to turn of Twixtor's interpolation during certain sections of the clip, while still taking advantage of the automation of the "speed %" variable?

Answer (score 1):

You could try making two copies of your footage, then disabling all the interpolation features within Twixtor on one of the copies - ie:

- Motion Vectors = None
- Image Prep  = None
- Motion Sensitivity = 0.00
- Frame Interp = Nearest

Keyframe the "speed %" controls on both tracks exactly the same, but then remove the appropriate track when you're running at 20% (maybe by keyframing opacity between 0% and 100%).

Let me know if it works.